# Apache beam : Read from multiple subscriptions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create a dataflow that listens to multiple subscriptions and writes to BigQuery. As per Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/multiple-pcollections), I can read multiple `PCollection` objects and combine them together.

However, looking at `PubsubIO.Read`'s javadoc [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/PubsubIO.Read.html#subscription-java.lang.String-), it seems `subscription` method accepts only one `String`. So, do we need to chain the `subscription` methods in order to read from multiple subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

Something you can do is to have multiple `Read`s from PubSub, where each reads from one subscription, and then `Flatten` their results.

Would that do what you need?

Comment: Agreed - create multiple subscriptions.